# How to solve this issue ("Resource GroupListField is not found Details") in wffm?

Tags: content-editor, wffm

Recently I installed the WFFM 8.1 upgrade-3 module in Sitecore (8.1 upgrade-3) on my local machine. When I was trying to open `Sitecore/components/website/call to action` it is showing an error like `Resource GroupListField is not found Details`.
How to solve this issue?
 Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appear when WFFM modules wasn't intalled correctly or some files are missing. In this case GroupListField.xml was missing.

I can't tell you the reason, you need to investigate logs file from the day you intalled the module.

Please check if the `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Modules\Web Forms for Marketers\Controls\constituent\GroupListField.xml` file exists in your Sitecore instance.

You could compare the file in the module package with file from your installation.

Comment: Hi,I dont have an that file in Applications "

Comment: Can you elaborate on the answer a bit - what should be done when the file is indeed missing to get wffm up and running?

Answer (score 0):

We encounter this issue after merging our code from another branch.

In my case we solved it by copying files (i.e. App_config,Bin,Views etc except for App_data) from a working Sitecore instance, preferably from a higher environment.

Ensure the following:

- you copied the files from CM and not the files from your CD site.
- you restored core, master, and web database from the same higher
  environment.
- make a backup of your configs(connectionstrings etc) just incase.